# Python 3.4: Error while installing scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm having problem with installing package SciPy for python 3.4 on Windows 10. There is an error I've got from cmd on admin mode. Other packages I installed correctly, such as numpy, scikit_learn, matplotlib.

[There is the error message](http://pastebin.com/T9tYBMMH)

Also I tried using

```
python pip -m scipy
```

But it didn't work out well. As the error message shows, probably there is sth with Lapack, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Because you try to install by source code, you need first compile and setting dependencies. Log file shows that not dependencies were found.
The hard way, download, compile and setting all dependencies. The easy way, you can use a python distrubution that install all for you (a lot packages by default, e.g. numpy, scipy, matplotlib, pandas, ipython, spyder). A good recommendation of python distribution is [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads).

Comment: ok, but how to do that. I mean, how to compile and set dependencies?

Comment: Do you really need compile by yourself dependencies instead of use a python distribution or precompiled versions?